# Are there any specifications or requirements for putting sound in software?

Tags: audio, software-design

I'm looking for information that talks about what kind of sounds to use in software. I'm adding sound to a software project. There must be information about sound design for computer programs, similar to a style guide for graphics, like material design.

So, are there specifications for sound design in software? If so, where do I find them?

Comment: Hey Gregory, although sound in software is surely an interesting topic, I fear, your question is very general and difficult to answer. A better way might be to first search for some general literature on the topic and then, if you have specific issues with implementing some of the strategies come back here to ask those specific questions.

Comment: Thanks ghost23! I'll be sure to ask a more specific question.Meanwhile, I found a page that dealt with this topic and there was a reference to a book that talks about it. I was thinking about adding that to this question. Let me rephrase my question.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no. There are no specifications from organizations that make specifications. Sound is an afterthought, it seems.

However, there is some information on this [page](https://uxplanet.org/the-role-of-sounds-in-ux-47adb8f82b38) by usplanet. The videos have some interesting facts. Who knew that Brian Eno (music producer, U2) produced the 95 sound that was played during the startup process? Fun fact, yeah?